# How to replace all df selected rows with one specific row in R

Tags: r, dataframe, replace

so i'm trying to change all the row values in the dataframe based on another dataframe like this:

df1:

| PROD | Num | Comment | --- |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.C.232 |  |  | --- |
| 1.C.231 |  |  | --- |
| 1.C.433 |  |  | --- |

df2:

| PROD | Num | Comment | --- |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.C.1612 | 1 | my cor. | --- |

desired output:

| PROD | Num | Comment | --- |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.C.1612 | 1 | my cor. | --- |
| 1.C.1612 | 1 | my cor. | --- |
| 1.C.1612 | 1 | my cor. | --- |

I tried the following, but it just replaces everything with one row:
`df1[, c("PROD", "Num", "Comment")] <- df2[, c("PROD", "Num", "Comment")]`

Answer (score 3):

It's simply

```r
df1[] <- df2
```

Here's a full reprex as a demo:

```r
df1 <- data.frame(Prod = c('1.C.232', '1.C.231', '1.C.433'), 
                  Num = rep('', 3), Comment = rep('', 3))

df2 <- data.frame(Prod = '1.C.1612', Num = '1', Comment = 'my cor.')

df1[] <- df2

df1
#>       Prod Num Comment
#> 1 1.C.1612   1 my cor.
#> 2 1.C.1612   1 my cor.
#> 3 1.C.1612   1 my cor.
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! just found the mistake that i did